# How to fix Codeigniter error: Call to a member function on null?

Tags: php, codeigniter, null, codeigniter-3

It's my first time exploring codeigniter and I've been trying to create a login where if users are not found in the database, it will redirect back to the login screen. I have not been successful because I've been getting this error:

[first error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNV7D.png)

Followed by

[second error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBwb9.png)

I've tried loading the database and session inside function verify() using

```
$this->load->database();
$this->load->session();
```

but even so, I didn't think it would work since I already declared database and session in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Here's the `controllers/Login.php`

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->view("templates/_header");
        $this->load->view("login");
        $this->load->view("templates/_footer");
        $this->load->view("templates/_scripts");
    }
    function verify(){
        $this->load->model('user');
        $check = $this->model->validate();

        if($check){

        } else {
        redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `models/User.php`

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Model{
    function validate(){
        $arr['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        $arr['password'] = password_hash($this->input->post('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
        return $this->db->get_where('users', $arr)->row();
    }
}
```

What do you guys think is the problem with it?

Comment: Full error message please, with a reference of what line it tells you is which line in your snippets.

Comment: @JonStirling I've added the Error messages. Stackoverflow didn't want to allow me to use blockquotes on them so I just took a screencap. Thanks

Comment: change `$check = $this->model->validate();` to `$check = $this->user->validate();`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It worked! Thanks! Any idea why `$this->model->validate();` didn't work?

Comment: @DavidDomingo you must call the name of the model you are referring to. Your model is user so you need to specify the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have load your `model` true way but to use it you have to call its class name (here is `User`) to work work correctly.

note: if you want to code in a clean way and don't conflict them try to name your models like `User_model` or `User_m`, so if you have a controller with name of `User` its not conflict with your model. 
:-)

Comment: Somebody said that I should use the class name too, `$check = $this->user->validate();`.Thanks for the tip about the model's naming convention. Having the same name for the model and controller has been confusing since earlier. Will be doing that now :D